# Is it possible to make a microwave frequency oscillator with an LC circuit?

Tags: oscillator, frequency, microwave, high-frequency

Can a Colpitts oscillator circuit consisting of pF value capacitors and nF value SMD inductors be used as a microwave frequency (within 500MHz, 5GHz) oscillator.

Comment: This seems to be another attempt at your [last question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/626088/how-do-electronic-devices-manage-to-create-2-ghz-oscillation), which was unanswered and closed for lack of detail.

Comment: I'm struggling :'(((

Comment: At this frequency the path log(length/width ratio) is an inductance but the tolerances dictate the accuracy. Also the area/ gap radio adds capacitance.  The standing wave ratio or wavelength also alters the impedance/ reactance.

Comment: Is it possible? Probably, but the devil is in the details. Rather than ask if it is possible, ask how to calculate the required values. Considering there are online calc, you need not ask. Once you have the theoretical values, then you are in a better position to consider if it is a valid solution.

Comment: Maybe try describing what you want to do, not how you want to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It won't work well to make a discrete 500 MHz Oscillator, without some experience and reason why you would want such a sensitive XO when specs for such are dependent on geometry and not just the discrete values.  As such, the phase noise would be exceptionally high and frequency tolerance and sensitivity too high, so these are never used.  Originally the technology increased dimensions to reduce the error on ratios and used low-loss materials. It all depends on the requirements (i.e specs)  When mixing frequencies this high, the differences are more significant.

Instead, high Q resonators are used mostly over 500 MHz or IC's with VCXO's in a PLL.
High Q resonators include XTAL, MEMS dielectric, and others.  The materials and process controls for high-precision, also drives the cost up significantly.  Thus there are many tradeoffs for spurious-free low phase noise, low temp.co., and low initial tolerance microwave oscillators that increases the complexity of the design.

The skill in design is to learn all these variables to find the best performance that meets your specs at the lowest cost.

Although not always best, [here](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/oscillators/172?s=N4IgjCBcpgnAHLKoDGUBmBDANgZwKYA0IA9lANogAMIAugL7EBMYArDdCGpFnkaRRBMAdADYA7AAIA4gAkAXiGIAWUVUkBZBUpCqqw%2BJu0rRTI4pPLzO1aOsnRw1na0Xdox7GVXXNiU6ZYQJdjd3hhcVZ7XXF1XxVxM3iYgGZhFKjk5Ujo7McmQyzxcWEmJkzQ7NgnXPg4yrrhWCpvFKSGlNqKt2V4EJ74cMLK5tzYMFLum3GAsZFWdp7YVia20Vh%2B6c2VDbF4ZwWx6tFDrNhq4bd2equqfSnidjBo9kdBl6oh%2BBzk1jBFnR-HyhP4PECgsTlF5gRxUDYvJg3QGIgwpTq-KEYy7I2AvFITTEgtF4tLoomkslXNHpYm-alohmUwEZPElbbglLYx7KJHc-Rc8HeF7KMGsbJOH4g3piYFXdgvViitQvNTCWWA0RpcTs1iJF6Sq6RSYvOom0X7VYC1iIE0XJjqx5eF7LZ0rFnJNS8kBqESfJnEH3CP0M6JqNJlZq4j1gB3emNq0Px0Sx0RsRMrUxg1OODy59mmL2mAEBspB-GEtxFoMp0ufUOl1hBesiAWmGvKMSwTn1rNMEpteEevuQwehUwXNqhlJSD3ThOzqNjnmhnlOXp9Fcp7xB1j%2B73bmEFTfpf5Z7cizXHs8d05Lm%2BI69OPfJm-4q-l9%2Bnz-P7e74v718WEfb4fw7b5gOKFczxKJgUkXStxVgp0PXlFC3XzZxjRQkplH-E4cJYUNdTVFhwKIgi4HIki8OVD1VTAeBcNDUxmJTZMn2eOiViBZiVnEZRp2Y-MPCcGMhNE3CNzoxwgWfES-ngnRczECRxNUuiYNvSt-GtZjwgrJTRHCA1DMUgN1mEf54E4scLPLLM7Jo6o2hhZjnKYYT3MzNz0g8hyvN0uiAvgJzfI8Hy2hnWznLkmLWwsrSlNiUNYlRKSx3ECYUz1D1EksvsUpEMBpyzPK2HzMqWNyorTCiytKr7Gz6pqxq8Mq588oMgNxGfU0PUY0NBgiZ9micdY4HzUbnCbD1RsSLNxlDGY8K7NVW1W3pAkW2a0l6EatQWrVU3EZCx2WVYlscXC01mq7rJG9bwj2pahhegwqEvWahiapSEAMf43us2DAf%2BWkzu%2B2CUhTP6gbRBaviWrzJuqP4TOIWIvViAkwViDtOSoQLQlx9I6nZWIcYJoN7WicmDBpj6sKJqh%2Bwpln-1iNmTnptm6p0Dn0l3bmamSWIUY8mmwAmHH-lmEX4yYuWZJ69mYTpuWhk%2BomGIMTUBUy6p2cRGmupARIYJ6mm3xFucj2t5y2D3fiJn4sncLVKHefRt2BN6GnpWZuEadQonEvRhZhZDx3FSaBAccJtxtUx1UPxFzWE6MmmjIMX2Rcy-6CtznGjQ%2BmaieL9ZHe1GnigiEVq5KNHTZO0obrLlGjLJvqiesqmcZ7k3xEY0pskRdnvgiH70dGEXS4TrwIjKRuTo7M3Ikd%2BfEj1hBojqL06nmHeWkPvHJ5AOoV6obtkjqN0zLPynvOvh%2BhSfjNk0Pt%2BeSq0Ib5Ur%2B91-h4ZQp9SaH0cCkR%2BP8GaxjqA3S%2Bh84FXygeEUGF4d5gD3trc4IC4ClB3qWKy%2BCwTwBSHvUhQZB4A2vuQ5mQNiHkIAZOahHZ37UJWKdNwJCSjEOXNfVckQ76MRgaoPBfCUY72Dpw9gO41iezPs4CRJRiqN32NUO4Ao%2BgTHOPsHerCf7hWvhnQxBsvzGJbsQuyACLJ12vhbWxu1YDLx3j1USxCXGghge4tgwCNFeLFP%2BMitiG4xgKG4koGxBFd04f3DRIUd4hVKHE6%2BQ8erskGBcBR18girD3M0L0eTGZuGaCId0oRinpHZM0WMVSZTRGaJUhmYJmgCnGPkqhZSZaZRNuMaprcilG2SEEU%2BQyI79ImJU6mgymFlOpO0opvCyk2MWZU8UjdlhNNomUoxZTkqDLWYPOpUSdAIDSEfQZ6UinjxOAJQ5bIxQuUOTFXJ08yldjqRtQOgyPkRPebtOE41flqn%2BbPY5G1hl-Vcl8iGzzqh33OLCu%2Bzw5BuAmHcO4UJkU6FRXcJFoRsUExkHiqmhKUVUysJi4gGDJlEqoPaJCdgKXgFpR2el0RUV0rglzRlVKWWcrBKizo3LL5egFV%2BIV9IX40vJVKuu3LqxRDlS0BlUr9hV0VQqmlyrSUfS1VioMhhFW4iFS87Vby5W4pRRgkVlkj7mrMHa6VpLiqOr1WmblbBrVsHtUS1y5qSEktdVwoUcrvUosRNalgcISoBspS3QVRKgIxvAC3XVsaWBcoTQxF1aaGIatJaRVNybSI5BDZRUtLpuUsHEckAkoa9VlDzfWgoBqE1MRDTc9t2bwD2ljASbwvrW2NrTUO7tkj60LBHdjQtBIjJSBDRbENLaw1HLTUDfigdF31IxQm%2BEIaNg4qTQSfdFr60bDrWmjYXaj3JnPUWjYG491eEYqpOV8bSX4mZreiYxJuVomtSGX91JaWqrZekASJaiUslfXqaDk70hqsg06OVV6gUoeAYetU5weo-qJZO64oHdwEzfXq60jFiOxtTGKollG2hwZowUAGcqWJMenAgL9MpcIKKY%2BFJj1k-hLr1fxWIpCuEYaE6Ycjyb%2BIkI8IMOD0mTrThw6SgTsaNhqFU8m%2B9GGEDFBPWp74ysH2hFvb6X2jKipJpENutw1nFRWcmIWkpI6RA8hczUCzTh0Xufs55xUTmxCNtoMQAADgAFygCAAAqgAOwAJZhYAPLoA0PgTAuAACuAAnfAIB6CMG9MgEAcWAAmkWAC0GCIChYi5AEAOgwsAE8Qu5bq%2BltA%2BWgA) are some examples in Xtal osc. or XO's, VCXO's with PLL's.